# Regular Expressions and TMatch.Groups.Count

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe

I'm porting some classes from the Apache Commons library, and I found the following behaviour strange. I have a regular expression defined as

```
const
    IPV4_REGEX = '^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$';
```

and I use it as follows:

```
ipv4Validator: TRegEx; 

ipv4Validator := TRegEx.Create(IPV4_REGEX);
```

When I use it to match an IP address, the following code returns false - the debugger shows that `Match.Groups.Count` is 5, which I didn't expect.

```
var
  Match: TMatch;
begin
  Match := ipv4Validator.Match(inet4Address);

  if Match.Groups.Count <> 4 then
      Exit(false);
```

Is this the correct behaviour of TMatch.Groups.Count?

---

Just in case, here's the full code of my class. Notice that I have commented the offending line, because it made my tests fail.

```
unit InetAddressValidator;

interface

uses RegularExpressions;

const
  IPV4_REGEX = '^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$';

type

  TInetAddressValidator = class
  private
    ipv4Validator: TRegEx;
  public
    constructor Create; overload;
    function isValid(const inetAddress: String): Boolean;
    function isValidInet4Address(const inet4Address: String): Boolean;
  end;

implementation

uses SysUtils;

constructor TInetAddressValidator.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  ipv4Validator := TRegEx.Create(IPV4_REGEX);
end;

function TInetAddressValidator.isValid(const inetAddress: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := isValidInet4Address(inetAddress);
end;

function TInetAddressValidator.isValidInet4Address(const inet4Address
  : String): Boolean;
var
  Match: TMatch;
  IpSegment: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Match := ipv4Validator.Match(inet4Address);

  // if Match.Groups.Count <> 4 then
  // Exit(false);

  IpSegment := 0;
  for i := 1 to Match.Groups.Count - 1 do
  begin
    try
      IpSegment := StrToInt(Match.Groups[i].Value);
    except
      Exit(false);
    end;

    if IpSegment > 255 then
      Exit(false);
  end;
  Result := true;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I suppose it never occurred to you that the Item array might be indexed from zero, like every other array in the world? Had your loop gone from zero to Count-1 instead of 1, you might have figured this out on your own.

Comment: @Rob, in fact his code is correct. Match.Groups[0].Value resolves to the whole IP address so that wouldn't play nice with StrToInt. Match.Groups[0] contains the whole matching expression.This is not documented so I understand his question.

Comment: @RobKennedy - yes, I know that. My question was if this is the correct behaviour - this is not very well documented, and not very intuitive. Also, it's bothersome that you cannot use `for g in match.groups do` without some weird conditional on the first item.

Comment: @RobKennedy You might think that, but this array is not indexed like every other array in the world. It runs from 0 to Count. And the documentation is sparse. I think you need to use offsite documentation to make sense of it. Or the source code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it actually runs from `0` to `Count - 1`. But the first element is not actually a group; that's what I find confusing. So we have a non-group as the first element; therefore, the total count doesn't equal the number of groups selected by the regex. Not exactly intuitive. And you are right: you cannot figure this out by reading the documentation or the interface. You have to either delve into the source code, or run a small test project to verify its behaviour. Hardly convenient.

Comment: You are right. I had to read the code to work this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match.Groups[0] contains the whole expression, so this is correct.

TGroupcollection constructor:

```
constructor TGroupCollection.Create(ARegEx: TPerlRegEx;
  const AValue: UTF8String; AIndex, ALength: Integer; ASuccess: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  FRegEx := ARegEx;
  /// populate collection;
  if ASuccess then
  begin
    SetLength(FList, FRegEx.GroupCount + 1);
    for I := 0 to Length(FList) - 1 do
      FList[I] := TGroup.Create(AValue, FRegEx.GroupOffsets[I], FRegEx.GroupLengths[I], ASuccess);
  end;
end;
```

As you can see the internal Flist (`TArray<TGroup>`) is initiated with the number of groups + 1.  FList[0] receives a group with offset 1 and the whole expression length. This behaviour is not documented.

Comment: I still wonder why it was designed this way. It doesn't seem very convenient (Java regexes, for example, don't do this.) May it be that this was designed to make it analog to '$0', '$1', etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Delphi's `TRegEx` is designed to mimic .NET's `Regex` class, which also adds the overall regex match to `Match.Groups.Count`.  .NET does this so that the `GroupCollection` class can implement the `ICollection` interface.

In Java `Matcher.group(0)` also returns the overall regex match.  `Matcher.groupCount()` returns the number of groups excluding the overall match.  Most regex libraries do it this way.